# Check if all inputs have value of zero with JS or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to check if ALL inputs (`.productTextInput`) have a value of zero.

If they are all zero then execute an alert, but only if they are ALL zero.

I have been able to check the first and all individually, but not all together.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="listQuantity">
        <input type="text" class="productTextInput" name="AddToCart_Amount" value="0">
    </div>
    <div class="listQuantity">
        <input type="text" class="productTextInput" name="AddToCart_Amount" value="0">
    </div>
    <div class="listQuantity">
        <input type="text" class="productTextInput" name="AddToCart_Amount" value="0">
    </div>
</div>
```

Script

```
$('.productTextInput').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() <= 1){
        alert("Must choose at least one product");
    } else {
        // do something
    }
});
```

Comment: Before somebody posts it yet **again**: No, you can't use `$('.productTextInput[value="0"]')` for this, it checks the *attribute*, not what the user entered: [Proof](http://jsbin.com/okosak/4) ([source](http://jsbin.com/okosak/4/edit)) Enter a non-zero value and click the button.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter) for this:

```
if ($('.productTextInput').filter(function() {
        return parseInt(this.value, 10) !== 0;
    }).length === 0) {
    // They all have zero
}
else {
    // At least one has a non-zero value
}
```

Comment: @DarrenDavies: Yeah. :-) But if you change the `.each` test to use `this.value` rather than the completely unnecessary `$(this).val()`, it almost catches up: http://jsperf.com/test-case122/2 (Not that it's likely that speed matters here.)

Answer (score 6):

```
$input_val = true;
$('.productTextInput').each(function() {
    if ($.trim($(this).val()) <= 1){
        $input_val = false;
        return false;
    } else {
        // do something
    }
});

if(!$input_val){
    alert("Must choose at least one product");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var valid = false;
$('.productTextInput').each(function() {
    if (!valid && this.value == 1){
        valid = true;
    }
});

if(!valid){
    alert("Must choose at least one product");
}
```

Comment: That logic's incorrect, isn't it? See my comment on Arun's answer (which has effectively the same code).

Comment: Yeah, it shows the alert even when one of the boxes is !0: http://jsbin.com/okosak/2/edit

Comment: Arun's fixed his now, so here's the comment I referred to above (which I've now deleted): *"That logic is incorrect, isn't it? You're using flag = true to mean they're all 0, but then you're setting your flag to false if any of them is <= 1. That doesn't make sense. (Also, there's a big difference between <= 1 and === 0.)"*

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.productTextInput').each(function( index, value ) {
    if (parseInt($(this).val())>0){alert("Must choose at least one product");}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a flag variable to check the case in the loop

```
var flag = true;
$('.productTextInput').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() != 0){
        flag = false;
        return false
    }
});

if(!flag){
    alert('at least one is more than 0')
}
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes fixed the problem